# Is there a way to access my wallet's private key? Recovering passcodes?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, private-key, password

Not sure if this is appropriate here, but I'm trying to recover a lost wallet by brute-forcing the passcode.

From a previous answer to the same question, it seems like the developers decided against exposing private keys to the users.

Is there any way to test potential passcodes to my wallet without resorting to Geth's CLI?

Comment: Check Hashcat maybe? https://hashcat.net/hashcat/

Answer (score 0):

Ideally there is no way to recover your password once you forget it.

But I came across this web site which I believe may be.

https://walletrecoveryservices.com/

Comment: Totally trustworthy - not. ;) Be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the EthTools.com [load wallet](https://ethtools.com/mainnet/wallet/load/) functionality and keep trying different passwords.

A video outlining its usage can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fyP9GFSEWI).

Good luck.